# Fast process each line of one file for each line in another file

Tags: python, performance, file

I have two text files. They contain about 75,000 (say file1) and 550,000 (say file2) lines. Files actually has comma separated csv format.

I need to match (by common field) lines from file1 to lines from file2 in one-to-many relation (so I can't stop processing at the first found match). In addition different lines from file1 could have same matches in file2 (so I can't remove already matched lines from file2).

I tried simple nested for-loops but it takes a lot of time to match those. I thought about generators but it's not a case here because I need to loop through file2 multiple times.
Is there a way to make it fast?

Upd. The order of files is doesn't matter. I read line from file1, split it to get some fields and compare with common field in line from file2. If match I add several fields from file2 to list for further actions.

Comment: A few clarification questions: 1) Do you care about the order of the lines in the files? i.e. Is there any problem with sorting the two files before performing the compare? 2) do you compare "entire line vs. entire line" or "field in line vs field in line"?

Comment: I'd read the data into a database. RDBMS are very fast at such comparisons.  But consider giving a minimal and complete example, if you want to do it in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of matching lines is different for those two files, I mean, if, for example, first line in file1 matches the last line in file2, than you have no other way to do what you want except reading one file into the memory. You can read it to something useful for search of the matches, for example, to `dict` to make it able to find the match for the line in `O(1)`.

Could you please provide two short example files to understand the matching rule? Then I'll try to write some code for that.

---

**UPDATE**

Since you've only provided two lines instead of two files, I tried to use my imagination.

I've created two files with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import random
with open('file1', 'w') as f1, open('file2', 'w') as f2:
    for _ in range(10):
        f1.write('{},{},{},{},track-{}\n'.format(*[random.randrange(5) for x in range(5)]))
        f2.write('stage-{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(*[random.randrange(5) for x in range(5)]))
```

file1:

```
4,4,3,1,track-0
3,1,0,2,track-0
1,2,3,1,track-3
0,1,2,1,track-2
0,0,4,2,track-2
0,2,3,1,track-0
0,4,4,0,track-0
2,1,4,3,track-1
2,1,4,1,track-1
1,1,0,3,track-4
```

file2:

```
stage-0,3,1,1,0
stage-3,2,1,0,1
stage-1,2,4,3,3
stage-0,4,0,1,3
stage-3,4,3,3,3
stage-0,0,3,2,1
stage-2,2,1,3,4
stage-4,3,1,0,3
stage-1,1,4,1,2
stage-3,0,1,3,4
```

Then, the following code:

```
import re

d, regex = {}, re.compile('stage-(\\d+)')
with open('file2') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        value = int(regex.match(line).group(1))
        if value not in d: d[value] = []
        d[value].append(line[:-1])

regex = re.compile('.*track-(\\d+)')

with open('file1') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        value = int(regex.match(line).group(1))
        print(line[:-1])
        if value not in d: print('  no matches')
        else:
            for x in d[value]: print('  MATCH: ' + x)
```

Provided the following output:

```
4,4,3,1,track-0
  MATCH: stage-0,3,1,1,0
  MATCH: stage-0,4,0,1,3
  MATCH: stage-0,0,3,2,1
3,1,0,2,track-0
  MATCH: stage-0,3,1,1,0
  MATCH: stage-0,4,0,1,3
  MATCH: stage-0,0,3,2,1
1,2,3,1,track-3
  MATCH: stage-3,2,1,0,1
  MATCH: stage-3,4,3,3,3
  MATCH: stage-3,0,1,3,4
0,1,2,1,track-2
  MATCH: stage-2,2,1,3,4
0,0,4,2,track-2
  MATCH: stage-2,2,1,3,4
0,2,3,1,track-0
  MATCH: stage-0,3,1,1,0
  MATCH: stage-0,4,0,1,3
  MATCH: stage-0,0,3,2,1
0,4,4,0,track-0
  MATCH: stage-0,3,1,1,0
  MATCH: stage-0,4,0,1,3
  MATCH: stage-0,0,3,2,1
2,1,4,3,track-1
  MATCH: stage-1,2,4,3,3
  MATCH: stage-1,1,4,1,2
2,1,4,1,track-1
  MATCH: stage-1,2,4,3,3
  MATCH: stage-1,1,4,1,2
1,1,0,3,track-4
  MATCH: stage-4,3,1,0,3
```

Not sure that this is what you wanted, however I tried to create big files, with 75K and 550K lines and it took 3 seconds to generate them and only half of the second to parse (without time of console output which took several minutes and was turned off by commenting `print`s out)

Comment: Line from file1: 3918,22162,7566537,1,track-30647
Line from file2: stage-763085,59.962689,30.408465,0,0.00
Matching field is the last in line1 and the first in line2.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that track-12345 matches stage-12345?

Comment: In this particular lines no, so this is an example of lines that doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks, I already found acceptable solution with similar idea being inspired by your previous suggestions. I sorted files, made from them two map-dictionaries where I grouped lines by unique stage/track fields and then processed through those maps. One more question: does regexp search faster then slicing and comparing strings?

Comment: That depends on the situation. I guess that in the current case the difference is minimal